# EXCEL XML Export Multiple Elements with different Attributes

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

I want to export data from Excel as XML data. I created the following XSD

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="test_root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="test_obj">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="element1"/>
                            <xs:element name="element2"/>
                            <xs:element name="element3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="subelement3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:attribute name="att_name"/>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Element1 and Element2 work fine, but the problem lies with the optional and repeatable Element3.

The final file can have multiple subelement3 instances that are distinguished by different values 
for the name attribute. For example the result should look like

```
<subelement3 name="test1">value1</subelement3>
<subelement3 name="test2">value1</subelement3>
...
```

Is that possible with Excel ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: If I try to drag subelement3 more than once on the excel sheet it says that it is already used. Also the value from the column is added as the value for the name attribute not the value of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't support recursive structures and therefore you can't map all of the elements.